# MSGraphClient post request

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

I am trying to do a post request via graph in a webpart - it keeps returning either fetch failed or 403. Can anyone please point in either a sample post request or how to fix

Ive confirmed via graph exploper that the api and post properties are correct and work. Just when I put in the webpart it fails :-(

```
this.props.context.msGraphClientFactory
      .getClient()
      .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
        client         
         .api("sites/MYSITEID/lists/MYLISTID/items")
         .version("v1.0")
          .post(MYFIELDS, (err, res, success) => {
            if (err) {  
                   console.error(err);  
              return;  
            }                
            if (success)
            {
              console.log("success");
            }
                  alert('Added');
          })//closes
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this to `package-solution.json`.

Example: When sending a mail,

```
"webApiPermissionRequests": [
      {
        "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
        "scope": "Mail.Send"
      }
    ]
```

And in the admin portal (API Management) it needs an approval (to use Graph Api).